# Create a new separate window in tkinter

Tags: python, windows, menu, tkinter

I want to create a new separate window, like opening a new page in Notepad.

This is what I have written:

```
import tinter
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Unitled Page")
        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Create New Page", command=self.onNewPage)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=fileMenu)

    def shutdown():
        pass

    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

    def onNewPage(self):
        pass

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x600")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which widget should I use for this purpose?

Comment: Check out the bottom of https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program.

Answer (score 4):

Create an instance of the [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) class.

Answer (score 0):

You ca use [pmw](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html) with [NnoteBook](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/NoteBook.html) if you want open a new page in the same windows. But you have to [install](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/starting.html) it before.